# Matching strings with at least one word in common

Tags: java, rdf, sparql, jena

I'm making a query to get the URIs of documents, that have a specific title. My query is:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> SELECT ?document WHERE {
  ?document dc:title ?title.
  FILTER (?title = "…" ).
}
```

where `"…"` is actually the value of `this.getTitle()`, since the query string is generated by:

```java
String queryString = "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> " +
                "PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> SELECT ?document WHERE { " +
                "?document dc:title ?title." +
                "FILTER (?title = \"" + this.getTitle() + "\" ). }";
```

With the query above, I get only the documents with titles exactly like `this.getTitle()`. Imagine `this.getTitle` is formed by more than 1 word. I'd like to get documents even if only one word forming `this.getTitle` appears on the document title (for example). How could I do that?

Comment: If you're going to post code that's not pure SPARQL, please add a language tag, and perhaps a library tag.  This _looks_ like it's probably Java, and using Jena, but that's not absolutely certain.  If it is using Jena, then you should consider using [ParameterizedSparqlString](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/query/ParameterizedSparqlString.html), because your code will break if the `this.getTitle()` contains a quotation mark.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for matches where `?title` and `this.getTitle()` have at least one word in common.  Probably the easiest way to do that is to turn the value of `this.getTitle()` into a regular expression that will match any of the words.  E.g., turn `"The Great Gatsby"` into `(The|Great|Gatsby)` and do a regular expression match.

Comment: I've edited your question, but in the future, if you're asking about a _query_, please post the query, and not (or at least, not _just_) the code that produces it.  Looking just at the Java code, it's not at all clear whether the query is correct or even legal, and if there's a bug in it, whether it's a bug of the query itself, or of the code generating the query.  Additionally, this really doesn't have anything to do specifically with Java or Jena,  it's just about a SPARQL query that involves some fixed string.  The _code_ really wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you've got some data like (in Turtle):

```
@prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/20203733/1281433> .
@prefix dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> .

:a dc:title "Great Gatsby" .
:b dc:title "Boring Gatsby" .
:c dc:title "Great Expectations" .
:d dc:title "The Great Muppet Caper" .
```

Then you can use a query like:

```
prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/20203733/1281433>
prefix dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>

select ?x ?title where {
  # this is just in place of this.getTitle().  It provides a value for
  # ?TITLE that is "Gatsby Strikes Again".
  values ?TITLE { "Gatsby Strikes Again" }

  # Select a thing and its title.
  ?x dc:title ?title .

  # Then filter based on whether the ?title matches the result
  # of replacing the strings in ?TITLE with "|", and matching
  # case insensitively.
  filter( regex( ?title, replace( ?TITLE, " ", "|" ), "i" ))
}
```

to get results like

```
------------------------
| x  | title           |
========================
| :b | "Boring Gatsby" |
| :a | "Great Gatsby"  |
------------------------
```

What's particularly neat about this is that since you're generating the pattern on the fly, you could even make it based on another value from the graph pattern.  For instance, if you want all pairs of things whose titles match on at least one word, you could do:

```
prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/20203733/1281433>
prefix dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>

select ?x ?xtitle ?y ?ytitle where {
  ?x dc:title ?xtitle .
  ?y dc:title ?ytitle .
  filter( regex( ?xtitle, replace( ?ytitle, " ", "|" ), "i" ) && ?x != ?y )
}
order by ?x ?y
```

to get:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| x  | xtitle                   | y  | ytitle                   |
=================================================================
| :a | "Great Gatsby"           | :b | "Boring Gatsby"          |
| :a | "Great Gatsby"           | :c | "Great Expectations"     |
| :a | "Great Gatsby"           | :d | "The Great Muppet Caper" |
| :b | "Boring Gatsby"          | :a | "Great Gatsby"           |
| :c | "Great Expectations"     | :a | "Great Gatsby"           |
| :c | "Great Expectations"     | :d | "The Great Muppet Caper" |
| :d | "The Great Muppet Caper" | :a | "Great Gatsby"           |
| :d | "The Great Muppet Caper" | :c | "Great Expectations"     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Of course, it's *very* important to note that you're pulling generating patterns based on your data now, and that means that someone who can put data into your system could put very expensive patterns in to bog down the query and cause a denial-of-service.  On a more mundane note, you could run into trouble if any of your titles have characters in them that would interfere with the regular expressions.  One interesting problem would be if something had a title with multiple spaces so that the pattern became `The|Words|With||Two|Spaces`, since the empty pattern in there might make *everything* match.  This is an interesting approach, but it's got a *lot* of caveats.

In general, you could do this as shown here, or by generating the regular expression in code (where you can take care of escaping, etc.), or you could use a SPARQL engine that supports some text-based extensions (e.g., [jena-text](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/text-query.html), which adds Apache Lucene or Apache Solr to Apache Jena).

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for asking it wrongly. I'm new here and I'm just starting with SPARQL.