# SPARQL query with FILTER returning correct values for its variables BUT only the given value for the variable being filtered

Tags: sparql, jena, dbpedia

I'm using `Jena` to make a `SPARQL` query to search for all a document's properties by its subject. But the documents can have more than one subject, and when I do the search, it doesn't return me all the documents' properties, including all the documents' subjects, but even if it has 3 subjects (for example) it returns me all the documents properties + only the subject I set at `FILTER`.

I'd like to have as a return all the properties from the found document + all the subjects (that belong to the found document) and not only the one at `FILTER`.

Query (`this.subject` is a variable that has its value set in a `JSF page`):

```
String queryString = "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> " +
                "PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> " +
                "PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> SELECT ?document ?subject" +
                " ?title ?description ?language WHERE { " +
                "?document dc:title ?title." +
                "?document dc:subject ?subject." +
                "?document dc:description ?description." +
                "?document dc:language ?language." +
                "FILTER ( regex(?subject, replace( \"" + this.subject + "\", ' ', '|' ), 'i' )). }";
```

Thank you!

Comment: Providing your query in plain text form (and not as the Java string you use) in the future would make your questions much easier to answer.  Also including sample data and the answers you get versus the answers you want would be very useful!

Comment: Also, and I know [I've mentioned this to you before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20407333/writing-sparql-queries-with-jena-to-query-for-iris-like-http-pt-dbpedia-org#comment30481831_20407333), using something like `( \"" + this.subject + "\",` is opening yourself up to all sorts of problems.  What happens if `this.subject` contains double quotation marks?

Comment: And the point that @RobV makes about including an actual query, not just code that produces a query, has also [been brought up before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203733/matching-strings-with-at-least-one-word-in-common#comment30148652_20203733).   We give this kind of advice because it will helps to get _you_ better answers, and because it reduces the number of things that could be going wrong.  E.g,, is something going wrong here because the intended query is wrong, or because the code that produces the query is wrong, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely want to use a sub-query to restrict to the documents matching the `FILTER` and then select the rest of the stuff you are actually interesting in e.g.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dc : <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

SELECT ?document ?subject ?title ?description ?language
WHERE
{
  { 
    SELECT ?document
    WHERE 
    {
      ?document dc:subject ?subject . 
      FILTER(REGEX(?subject, REPLACE("search term", " ", "|"), "i"))
    }
  }
  ?document dc:title ?title ;
            dc:description ?description ;
            dc:subject ?subject ;
            dc:language ?language .
}
```

Note that this is still going to give you a row for each document-subject combination so if you have a document with 3 subjects you'll get three rows for that document.  If you want to combine documents into a single row then you can use `GROUP BY` and then a `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregate, there are other questions already on Stack Overflow that detail how to do that.

#### Notes

Also note that using simple string concatenation to inject constants into your query is ill advised, take a look at Jena's [ParameterizedSparqlString](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/parameterized-sparql-strings.html) for a more user friendly and SPARQL injection proof API for building queries.

Comment: You don't need to search all that far,  the [SPARQL 1.1 W3C recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/) is right where it's always been.  Also if you search for [`"group by" [SPARQL]`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22group+by%22+%5Bsparql%5D) here on StackOverflow, you'll get plenty of examples.